# Plotting satellite ground track with calculated latitude and longitude at a given moment

Tags: orbital-elements, ground-track

I have obtained the Classical Orbital Elements for a satellite on a given epoch, and now I would like to plot them on a 2D map.

```
Epoch (UTC):    16 January 2021 02:36:14
Eccentricity:   0.0013696
inclination:    99.1927°
perigee height:     841 km
apogee height:  861 km
right ascension of ascending node:  32.9631°
argument of perigee:    196.2436°
revolutions per day:    14.12448643
mean anomaly at epoch:  163.8298°
orbit number at epoch:  61541
```

Which plots the following ground track:

[image]

Now, I would like to mathematically obtain the lat/long and be able to plot this. More specifically, what I would like to do, is pretty much the same thing that the approved comment here did: [Analytical expression for the ground track of the International Space Station](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43416/38283), but of course, with my COEs.

*code taken from the answer above, with only value modification*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

twopi = 2*np.pi
to_degs, to_rads = 180/np.pi, np.pi/180.

omega = twopi/(102*60) # the period is about 102 minutes
omega_E = twopi/(23*3600 + 56*60 + 4)

time = 60 * np.arange(101.) # 100 minutes

t0 = 0. # arbitrary, you can fit this later
inc = 81.
const = 1  # arbitrary, you can fit this later

x = np.cos(omega * (time-t0))
y = np.sin(omega * (time-t0)) * np.cos(to_rads*inc)
z = np.sin(omega * (time-t0)) * np.sin(to_rads*inc)

lon = np.arctan2(y, x) - omega_E * (time-t0) + const
lat = np.arcsin(z)

if True:
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(to_degs*lon, to_degs*lat, '.k')
    plt.xlim(-180, 180)
    plt.ylim(-90, 90)
    #plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.show()
```

Which results in a:

[image]

*Since we have an inclination of about 99 [deg], we can look at inclinations from 90 [deg] to 180 [deg] as -90 [deg] to 0 [deg]. So I assume that an inclination of ~81 [deg] should be correct in this plot.*

My questions here are:

1. How do I obtain the correct $t0$ (I was told that there answers on that on this site, but I am not sure how to look for it, so maybe a name/keyword for this would be enough for me to start looking for related questions/answers).
2. How do I obtain the correct $const$ (same thing as the question above).
3. Why does the plot stops at 0 [deg] lat, instead of continuing to reach the highest latitude, and then smoothly continue the line from the right to the left.

Comment: Related https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40266/geocentric-latitude-and-longitude-of-sub-satellite-point